# XSLT node have a group of duplicate elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am getting multiple RetrieveReplyDTO nodes and duplicate estimateNo fields. Requirement is , we have to find whether we are getting any duplicate estimateNo under RetrieveReplyDTO nodes and if we are getting any duplicate estimateNo , then check the creationDate and creationTime of that particular node "RetrieveReplyDTO " and get the latest estimate number .

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:retrieveResponse xmlns:ns0="some.url">
     <ns0:out>
        <ns0:replyElements>               
           <ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
              <ns0:estimateNo>1234</ns0:estimateNo>
              <ns0:estimateStatus>IN</ns0:estimateStatus>
              <ns0:creationDate>20170220</ns0:creationDate>
              <ns0:creationTime>111536</ns0:creationTime>
           </ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
           <ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
              <ns0:estimateNo>1234</ns0:estimateNo>
              <ns0:estimateStatus>IN</ns0:estimateStatus>
              <ns0:creationDate>20170225</ns0:creationDate>
              <ns0:creationTime>144500</ns0:creationTime>
           </ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>  
           <ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
              <ns0:estimateNo>4567</ns0:estimateNo>
              <ns0:estimateStatus>IN</ns0:estimateStatus>
              <ns0:creationDate>20170230</ns0:creationDate>
              <ns0:creationTime>144500</ns0:creationTime>
           </ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
           <ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
              <ns0:estimateNo>4567</ns0:estimateNo>
              <ns0:estimateStatus>IN</ns0:estimateStatus>
              <ns0:creationDate>20170229</ns0:creationDate>
              <ns0:creationTime>100045</ns0:creationTime>
           </ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>                            
        </ns0:replyElements>
     </ns0:out>
  </ns0:retrieveResponse>
```

Below XSLT I have tried

```
<xsl:template match="/replyElements">  <xsl:for-each-group select="ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO" group-by="ns0:estimateNo">   
  <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="ns0:creationDate" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="ns0:creationTime" order="descending" />
  </xsl:perform-sort> 
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>
```

I am getting below result:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><ns0:retrieveResponse ><ns0:out>
  <ns0:replyElements>
     <ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
              <ns0:estimateNo>1234</ns0:estimateNo>
              <ns0:estimateStatus>IN</ns0:estimateStatus>
              <ns0:versionNo>001</ns0:versionNo>
           <ns0:creationDate>20170225</ns0:creationDate>
              <ns0:creationTime>144500</ns0:creationTime>
           </ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
     <ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
              <ns0:estimateNo>4567</ns0:estimateNo>
              <ns0:estimateStatus>IN</ns0:estimateStatus>
              <ns0:creationDate>20170229</ns0:creationDate>
              <ns0:creationTime>100045</ns0:creationTime>
           </ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO>
  </ns0:replyElements>
```

It is giving second search estimationno data , not doing any sort. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `for-each-group` you can use a `for-each` with the `xsl:sort`s and then you can output the first item in sort order, that is, change

```
<xsl:template match="/replyElements">  <xsl:for-each-group select="ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO" group-by="ns0:estimateNo">   
  <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="ns0:creationDate" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="ns0:creationTime" order="descending" />
  </xsl:perform-sort> 
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="replyElements">  
<xsl:for-each-group select="ns0:RetrieveReplyDTO" group-by="ns0:estimateNo">   
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="ns0:creationDate" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="ns0:creationTime" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I have also changed the `match` pattern is the `replyElements` is not the root element in your input snippet.

Comment: Really thankful to you , it is working . I almost spent 2 days on this . Thanks aton.